# Install of Ubuntu on my Dell Latitude d510 results in computer freeze after 5 minutes

Tags: system-installation, laptop, cd

I downloaded the iso from ubuntu.com and burned it onto a CD-R with the program in the page.

The disc works properly in my desktop, but when I run it in my laptop another menu appears with the options:

- prove ubuntu
- install ubuntu
- check the memory
- check for errors
- run windows

When I try the install option, the screen shows "Ubuntu" in the center and littles points down (loading) and after 5 minutes the computer freezes.

What can I do?

Comment: So does this actually work? I have a blank latitude with no OS. Should the alternate iso work for me?

Comment: Would be good if you specify your computer specifications.

Answer (score 2):

Since it is an old computer probably your best bet is to use an alternate install CD instead of the live CD.

However, I hope you have at least 1 Gb of RAM (2Gb recommended), otherwise the system might be very slow.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using Lubuntu instead of plain Ubuntu.  It is designed to be a little bit more lightweight.

Its minimum specs are generally lower than those of Ubuntu.  Lubuntu uses the LXDE environment, instead of GNOME.

Its website is at http://lubuntu.net/, if you want to take a look at it.